# How do I write a function that returns an array containing object keys in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, object

```
var person = {
  firstName: 'Halle',
  lastName: 'Berry',
};

function names(object){
  var arr= [];
  for (var key in object) {
    arr.push(key);
    console.log(arr)
  }
}

names(person);
```

This is what i have so far. I am trying to return an array containing the object person keys.

Comment: Where is `function what() {}` declared? What is the program currently doing, and how is it different from what you expect it to do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Missing `return` statement, where is `what` declared?

Comment: Can you tell us which language this is (ideally by [edit]ing your question and adding the correct tag)?

Comment: Sorry I meant to put names when i called the function. I edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Object#keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) makes this simple:

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
console.log(Object.keys(arr)); // console: ['0', '1', '2']
```

---

Edit: By clarifying the question (thank you!) and comments received, the implementation was close: it was missing a return statement. Including [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) is a good practice to check whether keys belong to the object (true) or are inherited (false).

```
function names(object){
  var arr= [];
  for (var key in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      arr.push(key);
    }
  }
  return arr; // this was missing
}
```